# header not redirecting after login

Tags: php, html, redirect, mysqli, authentication

Hello guy's please i was hoping someone can help me here. Have seen many related question and have tried to implement it, but no luck.

here is my login code below:

```
            <?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['user_type']) && isset($_SESSION['user_id']))
    {
      header('Location: profile.php');
    }
    if(is_file('include/connection.php'))
    include_once('include/connection.php');
    else
    exit('Database FILES MISSING:(');
    ?>
    <?php $_SESSION['main_title']  = "Login"; ?>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

      foreach($_POST as $key => $value){

        if(empty($value)){
          $_SESSION['main_notice'] = $key." is required, fill all fields";  
          $empty = true;    
          break;
        }
      }

      if(isset($empty) && $empty){
        header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
      }
      else
      {
          extract($_POST);
          //$loginQuery = "select * from user where user_name = '$name' AND password = '$password' AND user_type = '$user_type'";
          $loginQuery = "select * from user where user_name = '$name' AND password = '$password'";
          $result = mysqli_query($con,$loginQuery);
          if(mysqli_num_rows($result)){

              $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);               
              $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['id'];
              $_SESSION['user_name'] = strtoupper($row['name']);
              $user_type = strtolower($row['user_type']);
              if(strtolower($user_type) == 'member'){   

                $_SESSION['user_type'] = 'member';  
                //header('Location: member-dashboard-home.php');
                header('Location: profile.php');

              }elseif(strtolower($user_type) == 'admin' || strtolower($user_type) == 'leader'){

                $_SESSION['user_type'] = strtolower($user_type);                                        
                //header('Location: admin-dashboard-home.php');
                header('Location: profile.php');
              }


          }else{
              $_SESSION['main_notice'] = "Invalid Details";
              header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
          }
      }
    }
    ?>
    <?php 
    if(is_file('include/header.php'))
    include_once('include/header.php');
    ?>
    <?php if(isset($_SESSION['main_notice'])) { ?>      
            <div class="main-notice">
              <p>
                      <?php
                      echo $_SESSION['main_notice']; 
                      unset($_SESSION['main_notice']);
                      ?>
              </p>
            </div>  
    <?php } ?>      
    <div>
      <form name="login" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
      <table>

        <tr>
          <td>User Name</td> 
          <td><input type="text" name="name" required><br></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Password:</td>
          <td><input type="password" name="password" required><br></td>
        </tr>
        <!-- <tr>
          <td>User Type</td>
          <td>
            <label for="user_admin">Admin</label><input type="radio" value = "admin" name="user_type" id="user_admin" required>
            <label for="user_member">Member</label><input type="radio" value = "member" name="user_type" id="user_member" required>
          </td>
        </tr> -->
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td><a href="register.php">Register</a></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      </form>   
    </div>
    <?php 
    if(is_file('include/footer.php'))
    include_once('include/footer.php');
    ?>
```

Please was am i doing wrong or missing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: If `include_once('include/header.php');` outputs anything to the browser that would explain the issue. **Or looking at the php error log** would have given you a clue

Comment: thanks RiggsFolly have make the coding more readable, it was an error when posting on here.

Comment: Header can only work if there is no output before. Did you check that? Output includes space like this space `<?php ?> <?php ?>`. Do you see it?

Answer (score 0):

You can perform the redirect using javascript.

```
function redirect($url) {
    echo '<script>window.location = "'.$url.'"</script>';
    die;
}
```

Just call the function when you need to redirect

```
redirect("profile.php");
```

Edit: This is a PHP function, if that was unclear.

Comment: thank hesonline, so how do i assign this to my current page. do i place at the top or bottom. sorry for my lack of knowledge very new to php.

Comment: I don't know how you have structured your project, but you can insert the function after session_start(); if you don't have a separate file where you store general functions, or something similar i.e bootstrap or some class.
To perform the redirect, replace header("Location: profile.php"); with redirect("profile.php");

Comment: hi hesoline. i manage to follow your instruction. at the moment i don't have extra function store. have manage to get it working. here is the screen shot of the code where i place it. http://prntscr.com/bo0isd

Comment: Now remove `header("location: profile.php");` and put `redirect("profile.php");` instead.

Comment: yes have done that and he now works. thanks appreciate it.